# ANTLR4 python target not working with some special rule names

Tags: python, antlr4

For example, if my grammar contains a rule named `state`:

```
// Grammar.g4
grammar Grammar;

program : state* EOF ;
state: 'break;' | 'continue;' | 'return;' ;
```

The `GrammarParser.py` generated by `antlr4 -Dlanguage=Python3 Grammar.g4` will raise an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File ".../GrammarParser.py", line 96, in program
    self.state()
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

This is because each ANTLR rule turns into a Python method. The name `state` conflicts with an existing field/method used by ANTLR runtime internally:

```
class GrammarParser ( Parser ):
    def program(self):
        ...
            ...
                ...
                self.state = 4
                self.state()
                self.state = 9
                ...
```

Other rule names like `match`, `atn` or `consume` also lead to various runtime exceptions:

```
# match:
TypeError: GrammarParser.match() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

# atn:
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'states'

# consume:
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Although this can be easily fixed by renaming the rule, the exception looks confusing especially to beginners, and it can take quite a long time to realize the cause for a large grammar file. I believe ANTLR4 should give a warning or rename the rule ([as it already does for keywords](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/873a01ca2939e623f396d356f9e903b9afd4ca32/tool/src/org/antlr/v4/codegen/target/Python3Target.java#L15)) if a name conflict is detected.

Since ANTLR4's GitHub requires asking on StackOverflow before opening a issue, do you believe it is a ANTLR bug?

Comment: This is a bit opinion based but I would think that it is a bug if using particular identifiers produces seemingly unrelated error messages.

Comment: It is a bug because renaming symbols on codegen that would otherwise result in a symbol conflict was added in 4.10. Runtime classes, fields, and methods should not conflict with symbols in the grammar. The usual fix involves adding the name into the keyword table [here](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/873a01ca2939e623f396d356f9e903b9afd4ca32/tool/src/org/antlr/v4/codegen/target/Python3Target.java#L15).